# What is mean `alloc factor 0.900000 0.900000` after using 'ps -A | firefox'?

Tags: debian, firefox, ps

My browser stopped responding. I closed firefox, and tried opening it again. Firefox did not run, so I typed `ps -A`:

> 7122 ?        01:07:56 firefox-esr

I'm not killing this process, and type:

`ps -A | firefox`:

I get these 2 strings:

> alloc factor 0.900000 0.900000
>
> alloc factor 0.900000 0.900000

[image]

After `ps -A | firefox` command I get this:

[image]

What is that output, and why did I get it?

Comment: *Why* are you piping the output of `ps` into Firefox?  What did you expect to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a mistaken command:

```
ps -A | firefox
```

when you meant to type:

```
ps -A | grep firefox
```

To stop any existing firefox process, try: `pkill firefox-esr` or `pkill -9 firefox-esr`

Comment: I right understand: if Firefox is not responding, and I type `ps -A | firefox` , I get alloc factor, right?

Comment: 'Cos if Firefox works correct, and I type `ps -A | firefox`, this command open another firefox